# C# / Send keys combination (CTRL+S) to another window

Tags: c#, winapi, window, sendkeys, sendmessage

I am trying to send keys combination to another program like that:

```
// keydown ctrl
SendMessage(windowBracketsKeyListener, 0x100, (IntPtr)VK_CONTROL, (IntPtr)0x001D0001); 
// keydown S
SendMessage(windowBracketsKeyListener, 0x100, (IntPtr)VK_S, (IntPtr)0x001F0001); 
SendMessage(windowBracketsKeyListener, 0x102, (IntPtr)115, (IntPtr)0); 
// keyup ctrl 
SendMessage(windowBracketsKeyListener, 0x101, (IntPtr)VK_CONTROL, (IntPtr)0xC01D0001);
```

To the last line I have an error (look at the image below).

I send the same commands as in Spy++. So firstly I automatically tried to click <kbd>CTRL+S</kbd> on a window then checked what I get in Spy++ and wrote the same commands.

Error:

```
System.OverflowException: 'Arithmetic operation resulted in an overflow.'
```

- Okay, I use not Spy++, but Window Detective to be honest.

[image: Image with my commands, commands from Window Detective and received error]

Comment: C# hexadecimal literals are signed, which can cause sign bit problems.  You might want a `u` suffix on the hex value, or else `(IntPtr)unchecked { (uint) 0xhexvalue }` to make sure that sign-extension does not kick in.

Comment: That 3rd line looks suspect. Are you trying to send a keyup for S? You comments in the image don't match what you are calling. Don't you want to do: keydown ctrl, keydown s, keyup s, keyup ctrl? The full exception and stack track would be useful.

Comment: @BenVoigt , I am not sure that understand you correct. When I don't convert to IntPtr I get an error: "cannot convert from 'uint' to 'System.IntPtr'"

Comment: @shox , code on image is dirty. second and third lines there to send "s" key. And "s" key is sending without problem. As you see on Window Detective the same, but I get error on 4th line.

Comment: Isn't dec 102 the F4 key? Looks like you might not want the S keydown but rather send the character. See this: https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/sqlserver/en-US/6424df9e-514c-405a-89c3-f88b979be41d/how-can-i-preform-a-simulation-of-a-key-pressclick-using-send-message-?forum=csharpgeneral . Just because the error is on that line doesn't mean it's not the previous line that is at fault. Again, add your stack trace. Having a commet that says "keyup ctrl" that is keydown of a different button is not good. Don't use any comments if you are going to have them wrong

Comment: @shox , Okay. 
I tried code from those site. But when I executed I get symbol "<" in editor. 
Code which I used:
       [System.ComponentModel.TypeConverter(typeof(System.Windows.Forms.KeysConverter))]
[System.Flags]
[System.Runtime.InteropServices.ComVisible(true)]
public enum Keys {
ControlKey = 118,
S = 62
}
public void Combination(IntPtr handle)
{
SendMessage(handle, WM_KEYDOWN, (int)Keys.ControlKey, 0);
SendMessage(handle, WM_CHAR, (int)Keys.S, 0);
SendMessage(handle, WM_KEYUP, (int)Keys.ControlKey, 0);
}

Comment: In "the" editor? In VS, in chrome? What does windows detective show?

Comment: @shox , Editor - Visual Studio. In detective: keydown - VK_F7, keyup - return value = 0

Comment: [You can't simulate keyboard input with PostMessage](https://devblogs.microsoft.com/oldnewthing/20050530-11/?p=35513) (or SendMessage())

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is not much point in faking the `WM_KEYDOWN/WM_KEYUP` messsages, only send the message they generated. Just the two `WM_CHAR` messages.

Please [use SendKeys.Send(String) Method](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.windows.forms.sendkeys.send?redirectedfrom=MSDN&view=netcore-3.1#System_Windows_Forms_SendKeys_Send_System_String_) instead.

> To specify that any combination of SHIFT, CTRL, and ALT should be held
>   down while several other keys are pressed, enclose the code for those
>   keys in parentheses. For example, to specify to hold down SHIFT while
>   E and C are pressed, use "+(EC)". To specify to hold down SHIFT while
>   E is pressed, followed by C without SHIFT, use "+EC".

The following sample works for me:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Diagnostics;
using System.ComponentModel;
using System.Runtime.InteropServices;
using System.Windows.Forms;

namespace Test
{
    static class Program
    {
        [DllImport("user32.dll")]
        public static extern int SetForegroundWindow(IntPtr hWnd);
        static void Main()
        {

            Process[] processes = Process.GetProcessesByName("notepad"); //notepad used be test

            foreach (Process proc in processes)
            {
                SetForegroundWindow(proc.MainWindowHandle);
                SendKeys.SendWait("^(s)");
            }
        }
    }
}
```